# Como armazenar em Python valores de um print em uma variável?

Tags: python, pandas

Importei dados de uma tabela em Google Sheets usando o Pandas e criei um data frame. Renomeei suas colunas e fiz um for loop para filtrar dentre uma dessas colunas, os valores a abaixo de 20, porém, só consigo ver o resultado com um print. Além disso, não consigo armazenar esses valores em uma variável. Por exemplo, para usa-las posteriormente em um gráfico.

Já tentei criar a variável antes do print. Já tentei converter em `str` ou em `int`.

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
import gspread
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
gc = gspread.authorize(GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())
worksheet = gc.open('CSV').sheet1
rows = worksheet.get_all_records()
import pandas as pd
tabela = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows)
tabela.set_index((["nome","idade","pet","jardim","casada"]))
idades =tabela["idade"]

for x in idades:
    if x <=20:
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira é usar o `loc`

Exemplo:

### Criando dataframe de teste

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"idade": [18, 22, 19, 21], "nome": ["Joao", "Pedro", "Sergio", "Murilo"]})

>>> print(df)
   idade    nome
0     18    Joao
1     22   Pedro
2     19  Sergio
3     21  Murilo
```

### Filtrando

```
>>> df.loc[df["idade"] <= 20]
   idade    nome
0     18    Joao
2     19  Sergio
```

**Nota** vc pode associar o resultado a um novo dataframe

```
>>> df1 = df.loc[df["idade"] <= 20]

>>> print(df1)
   idade    nome
0     18    Joao
2     19  Sergio
```

### Usando mais de uma condição

```
>>> df1 = df.loc[(df["idade"] <= 20) & (df["nome"] == "Sergio")]

>>> print(df1)
   idade    nome
2     19  Sergio
```

**Nota** Repare que cada condição está entre parentesis.

**Nota** Use `&` para `and`, `|` para `or` e `~` para `not`

Comment: Legal, muito obrigada por me responder, mas será que usando o loop for não é possível? Pois tenho casos também de for if com duas ou mais condições, nesse caso acho que essa opção seria interessante.

Obrigada

Comment: Post atualizado para mais de uma condição. Em tempo: EVITE usar o `for` em dataframes. Existem várias maneiras melhores no que diz respeito principalmente à performance.

Comment: ahh não sabia, como deve percebido, sou novata em Python! Vou usar dessa forma que me ensinou!

Comment: @Flavia Você está aprendendo, entre no perfil do [Paulo Marques](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/208011/paulo-marques?tab=answers) e estudes as resposta que ele publicou no site. ele sabe do que está falando e também pesquise [aqui no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas?tab=Votes) perguntas e respostas de outros autores.

Comment: Sim, tenho feito isso, pesquiso muito, é primeira vez que pergunto pois realmente não sabia mais onde buscar!